# How to compile c code taking advantage of CPU specific features

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcc4.8

If on linux I try to compile c code in the standard way

```
gcc -myprog.c
```

the generated binary uses only the base CPU features, since the modern CPUs have a lot of special features to increase the performances, like AVX, AVX2, SSE3, SSE4 etc. according the model

Since I want targeting only a specific CPU type (i7 Sandy Bridge), Is there a way to set the copiler to take advantage of these features?

Comment: GCC is the Swiss Army knife of compilers. If you want to take advantage of Intel specific features, Intel's own compiler is probably worth looking at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development

Comment: On x86 and x86-64, `gcc -W -Wall -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native -mtune=native` builds highly optimized code for the current processor (with warnings, which I always recommend). You can use e.g `gcc -c -W -Wall -Q -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native -mtune=native --help=optimizers | less` to see which detailed options are enabled, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) for explanations on each.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: That would already constitute part of a better answer than the one already present.

Comment: `gcc -myprog.c` is not the standard way... It's rather likely that that would produce some interesting errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the -march and -mtune [gcc flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html)